# How to seamlessly shift from "connaître" to "savoir"?

Tags: grammaire, constructions

I just said in conversation:

> J'en suis arrivé à **connaître** toute sa garde-robe, et même quel genre de vêtements elle préfère porter pour quelle occasion.

... only to realise later that I didn't place the verb "savoir" before the phrase "quel genre":

> J'en suis arrivé à **connaître** toute sa garde-robe, et même à **savoir** quel genre de vêtements elle préfère porter pour quelle occasion.

Perhaps, I unwittingly saw fit to drop the *2nd* verb "savoir", as I already used "connaître". But grammatically speaking, "connaître" cannot take the form of "connaître quel genre ...".

As redundant as it seems to place "connaître" and "savoir" so close to one another, is it necessary to do so, after all? Or is it acceptable to drop "savoir" as long as the sentence is understandable without it? Or maybe another solution?

Comment: I didn't realize there was any issue with this sentence when I first read it. So I guess it's ok.

Comment: Un peu en marge, mais un exemple «officiel» excessivement plus disgracieux que votre exemple, qui ne me choque pas davantage qu'il a choqué @StéphaneGimenez: le nom officiel des cours de sport dans les écoles publiques du Québec est [*éducation physique et à la santé.*](http://www1.education.gouv.qc.ca/progressionPrimaire/educationPhysique/)

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to avoid the discrepancy:

> *J'en suis arrivé à connaître toute sa garde-robe, et même le genre de vêtements qu'elle choisira de porter en fonction de telle ou telle occasion.*